# for infinito en c

Tags: c, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo un mini programa, el cual, permite la entrada de datos de clientes, y la opción "u" muestra el listado de todos los clientes metidos en el sistema.

Resulta que no se que estoy haciendo mal, porque cuando quiero mostrar todos los clientes, me sale un bucle infinito. Gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
switch(opcion){
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        do{
            nuevopaciente();
            printf("Otro paciente (S/N)? ");
            scanf("%s",&otropaciente);
            
        }while(otropaciente=='s' || otropaciente=='S');
        break;

    case 'u':
    case 'U':
            
        do {
            system("cls");
            printf("Lista de pacientes y su ubicaci%cn:\n",162);
            for(a=0;a<i;a++){
                printf("\t%s %s\n",nombre[a],apellido[a]);
            }
            printf("\npresione 'm' para regresar al menu principal, o presione 's' para salir\n");
            scanf("%s",&salir);
            if(salir=='s'){
                exit(-1);
            }
        }while(salir!='m'); //
            
        system("pause");
        break;
      
    case 's':
    case 'S':
        exit(-1);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Que valor tiene `i` en `for(a=0;a<i;a++)` porque no veo que la estes definiendo

Comment: procura no usar variables globales... no te van a aportar nada salvo, quizás, problemas

Comment: Saludos. Hace falta más detalle; mencionas que con la opción *u* el bucle se genera pero no si es que `printf("\t%s %s\n",nombre[a],apellido[a]);` es el bucle o cuando presionas para salir (es decir `printf("\npresione 'm' para regresar al menu principal, o presione 's' para salir\n");`) se genera. Observo que con el `case` (digamos) validas mayúsculas y minúsculas; dentro de opción *u* tanto la *s* como la *m* solo checas minúscula.

Comment: existe alguna manera de poner todo mi código? no lo he podido poner porque me indica que es demasiado largo. Consta de 79 líneas.

Comment: me respondo a mi mismo.... he generado una función fuera de la función principal "main". De esa manera, evito que se haga un bucle infinito. como no puedo poner todo el código porque es muy largo, pongo una imagen del mismo. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Lo que te he puesto en la respuesta ... cambia los `%s` por `%c` al leer `char`

Answer (score 3):

Tu código no está completo y puede que por ello mi respuesta sea igualmente incompleta. No obstante el error tiene la suficiente gravedad como para responder.

```
scanf("%s",&otropaciente);
```

En esta línea tenemos un error sí o sí:

- Si `otropaciente` es de tipo `char`, el uso de `%s` hará que se escriba más de un caracter, por lo que se podrían sobreescribir otras variables y eso provocar un comportamiento extraño en el programa. Para leer caracteres hay que usar `%c`.
- Si `otropaciente` es de tipo `char*` o `char[]`, entonces sobra el `&`. `otropaciente` ya sería un puntero y el uso del `&` solo serviría para escribir valores donde no nos interesa

Para una respuesta más completa así como destacar otros posibles errores es necesario que edites tu pregunta y añadas todo lo que falta.